# How to pass a parameter to a subquery in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery

I need to convert the following query written in SQL-Server for PL / SQL but I cant pass a parameter to a subquery.

```
select 
     p.ID,
     case 
        when p.column1 = 1 
      then (select top 1 sub.column1 from internal sub where sub.Id = p.Id)
     end SubQueryWithParameter
from
     parent
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly at you subquery:

```
select top 1 sub.column1 from internal sub where sub.Id = p.Id
```

probably you want:

```
select sub.column1 from internal sub where sub.Id = p.Id and rownum=1
```